# SantaRosa and RAM limit

Tags: memory, memory-limit

I have a notebook on the SantaRosa platform (HP 6710s) in the manual it says that it can use 2GB RAM memory strips max. (there are two slots so 4 GB total). I wonder what would happen if I try to put in two sticks of 4GB each, does it have a chance to work?

Comment: For the record it works correctly with 8 GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always the posibility that the documentation was printed before there were 4gb modules on the market. I have run into this before with laptops that state 2x1gb as the max, but they run fine with 2x2gb. Some have required a BIOS update to acheive this though.

One of the following will happen: it will work and display 8gb (assuming you have a 64bit OS), or as BloodPhilia stated above.

I do not have one of those laptops lying around to test with unfortunately, so cannot offer any guarantee. If you have the ram, give it a try. If you are planning on purchasing ram, make sure you have a good return policy  :-)

Comment: Currently I do not have I consider buying.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably either not detect the memory at all or just detect (and thus use) only 2 GB each.